# Midrashim That Contain Elements That are Against Nature

Tags: sources-mekorot, midrash

I a compiling a list of midrashim that contain elements that go against the laws of nature (e.g. Og's picking up a mountain the size of the camping of Bnei Yisrael).   Can anyone help me?

Comment: What is your intent?  Who will be your audience?  It sounds like you are making midrashim which require a high level of expertise to interpret accessible to the novice!  That doesn't sound helpful.

Comment: It seems to me that such a list would be extremely long - book-length. If you're working on such a list, I wish you success with your project, and suggest that perhaps you could reformulate your question here to ask for help with *methods* for tracking examples down, making sure they fit, etc., rather than ambiguously asking for help, which could be interpreted as asking for a book-length answer, here.

Comment: I agree with closing this question because it cannot be reasonably answered in its current form, but the phrase "not a real question" is unhelpful. It is real; someone asked it. There it is for everyone to see. It exists. Can the moderators please change that "real" phrase to something, uh, real?